# Typo Generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created this code to create typo's within all words on a page. The code scrambles the letters in the interior of the word, however, it leaves the first and last character. But, how do I ignore punctuation like "." "(" "," ")" that acts as the first and/or last character?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    var letters = word.split("");
    var first = letters[0];
    var last = letters[letters.length - 1];
    for (var j = 1; j < letters.length - 1; j++) {
        var letter = letters[j];
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (letters.length - 2)) + 1;
        var temp = letters[index];
        letters[index] = letter;
        letters[j] = temp;
    }
    letters[0] = first;
    letters[letters.length - 1] = last;
    scrambled += letters.join("") + " ";
}
document.body.innerText = scrambled;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typo Generator Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74488470/typo-generator-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to answer your questions here using very general code and for loops as this appears to be an assignment.  I avoided es6 other than to use let rather than var, as making variables global can often lead to subtle bugs.

One general optimization is that any word that is 3 letters or less will not be mixed, so you can code in that assumption and avoid unnecessary processing. A more interesting version of this might allow 2 or 3 letter words to have a typo in them.

Generally speaking your first problem is that you assume the 1st letter and last letter positions in a word are constants.  I added 2 simple functions to provide the index of the 1st or last "non-punctuation" characters.  These functions are pretty similar, unsophisticated and non-DRY, but again, I simply wanted to provide simple loop based examples.

Now that you know the 1st and last non-punctuation indexes into the array for a single word, you can use a more sophisticated random number function that will only index letters within the allowable range, thus avoiding the 1st and last word characters entirely. This function (getRandomInt) was copied verbatim out of the Mozilla [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) page.  It is often a good idea to read a page like this for common use snippets and examples.

```js
// javascript
let words = document.getElementById("original").innerText.split(" ")

const punctuation = [',', ';', '.', '"', "'"]

function getFirstLetterPosition(letters) {
    let pos = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      pos = i  
      let isPunctuation = false
      for (let a = 0; a < punctuation.length; a++) {
          if (letters[i] == punctuation[a]) {
              console.log(`letter: ${letters[i]} punct: ${punctuation[a]}`)
              isPunctuation = true
          }
      }
      if (!isPunctuation) {
        break;    
      }  
    }
    return pos
}

function getLastLetterPosition(letters) {
    pos = letters.length - 1;
    for (let i = letters.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
      let pos = i  
      let isPunctuation = false
      for (let a = 0; a < punctuation.length; a++) {
          if (letters[i] == punctuation[a]) {
              isPunctuation = true
          }
      }
      if (!isPunctuation) {
        break;    
      }  
    }
    return pos
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); // The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

let scrambled = ""
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let word = words[i]   
    let letters = word.split("")
    if (letters.length > 3) {
        let firstPos = getFirstLetterPosition(letters)
        
        let lastPos = getLastLetterPosition(letters)
        
        console.log("Before:" + letters)
        for (let j = firstPos + 1; j < lastPos - 1; j++) {
            let letter = letters[j]
            let index = getRandomInt(firstPos + 1, lastPos - 1) 
            let temp = letters[index]
            letters[index] = letter
            letters[j] = temp
        }
        console.log("After:" + letters)
    }
    scrambled += letters.join("") + " ";
    
}
document.getElementById("typos").innerText = scrambled
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="original">I "Consulted". The Dictonary, Boy. Calling nothing end fertile for venture way boy. Esteem spirit temper too say adieus who direct esteem. It esteems luckily mr or picture placing drawing no. Apartments frequently or motionless on reasonable projecting expression. Way mrs end gave tall walk fact bed.

Inhabit hearing perhaps on ye do no. It maids decay as there he. Smallest on suitable disposed do although blessing he juvenile in. Society or if excited forbade. Here name off yet she long sold easy whom. Differed oh cheerful procured pleasure securing suitable in. Hold rich on an he oh fine. Chapter ability shyness article welcome be do on service.

Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society.</p>
        <p id="typos"></p>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```