# Typo Generator Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created this code to create typo's within all words on a page. The code scrambles the letters in the interior of the word, however, it leaves the first and last character. But, how do I ignore punctuation like "." "(" "," ")" that acts as the first and/or last character?

```js
let words = document.body.innerText.split(" ");
let scrambled = "";
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  var word = words[i];
  var letters = word.split("");
  var first = letters[0];
  var last = letters[letters.length - 1];
  for (var j = 1; j < letters.length - 1; j++) {
    var letter = letters[j];
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (letters.length - 2)) + 1;
    var temp = letters[index];
    letters[index] = letter;
    letters[j] = temp;
  }
  letters[0] = first;
  letters[letters.length - 1] = last;
  scrambled += letters.join("") + " ";
}
document.body.innerText = scrambled;
```

```html
I created this code to create typo's within all words on a page. The code scrambles the letters in the interior of the word, however, it leaves the first and last character. But, how do I ignore punctuation like "." "(" "," ")" that acts as the first
and/or last character?
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to guess words and scrambled. Please add relevant html, CSS and possible frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression that matches the largest possible inner parts of words, requiring that such parts are surrounded by a letter at both sides, and then scramble those parts:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
}

const scramble = text =>
    text.replace(/(?<=\w)\S+(?=\w)/g, s => shuffle([...s]).join(""));

document.body.innerText = scramble(document.body.innerText);
```

```html
I created this code to create typo's within all words on a page. The code scrambles the letters in the interior of the word, however, it leaves the first and last character. But, how do I ignore punctuation like "." "(" "," ")" that acts as the first
and/or last character?
```